# custom panorama street view, on flash street view player

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

V3 google maps api has detailed information on how to create custom panoramic street views using the html5(?) player. as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview
For the flash version of street view, there is no example or tutorial, on how to make a custom panoramic view: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services#StreetviewOverlays
This question had been raised several times in the past, before api v3, and never answered, since the answer came later, for the html5 street view player. Has anyone now managed to create a custom panorama street view with the flash player? (since the flash street view player quality is still better, eg. being used in google art project, business photos etc.)

Rgrds,
Minos

Comment: To speak with examples: how to make this: http://tinyurl.com/d46zoef  using this flash player: http://tinyurl.com/dyulqfk

Comment: V3 is deprecated, and could be shut off in less than a year so it doesn't make sense to invest much effort creating V2 code.

Comment: @ManoMarks Marks I am talking about this player used here: http://www.googleartproject.com/collection/the-metropolitan-museum-of-art/museumview/ and here: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/businessphotos/ and as described in google maps V2 api:"Note: although Street View functionality is designed to be used in conjunction with a map, this usage is not required. You may use a standalone Street View object without a map" it seems that the flash street view player, although associated with v2 gmaps api, can be also independently used.

Comment: Those are Google projects, they may look like V2 but it's really a different branch.

Comment: Thanks @ManoMarks So where could I find documentation or seek advocation about how to customize the google street view flash player, similar to the one for the html5 google street view player? I' ve gone that far by now: http://tinyurl.com/cv94hot, with the html5 player discribed in v3, but is the player in flash with better quality that i need to get info about.

Comment: All the documentation on V2 can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/. Since it's deprecated, no more is being produced, only bug fixes. Check out the reference for Street View Panorama here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GStreetviewPanorama And again, I urge you not to spend your time on this as when the cutoff happens, you'll be back asking for an extension that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

well thanks @ManoMarks , but it seems that the flash street view player is Independent of api version and can be used on version 3 too. I am quoting again from google documentation: "although Street View functionality is designed to be used in conjunction with a map, this usage is not required. You may use a standalone Street View object without a map" but is does not explain how to use it without a map or with map V3 (or I don't see the explanation).  Additionally http://goo.gl/maps/RBIV here on a desktop I get the flash street view player, so it seems to me that google will keep using it in parallel to the html5 street view player in mobiles. Additionally, it seems that google further uses 
and supports this player in other new projects like google art project and business photos, with or without a map, and independent of map api version. I would accept an answer like :" the flash street view panorama player is not supposed to support use of custom panorama, or that google does not plan to provide any documentation about how to do it, like it happens for the html5 street view panorama player" but I am not getting such an answer. So I will ask again and excuse me for insisting: Can I use a custom panorama using this flash street view player? http://tinyurl.com/84wdwar which is the same with this flash street view player www.goo.gl/maps/xy6r which is the same with this flash street view player www.maps.google.com/help/maps/businessphotos/  simply embedded from here: www.goo.gl/maps/Q79U. I know it may be confusing and too specific what I am trying to figure out, but I did everything I can to clarify it. I 've searched all the info available, but there is no clear answer.

Comment: If i am wrong, and flash panorama street view player is solely part of api v2 and If all the above examples are still using v2 api, and none uses v3 please do correct me. That will mean that maps.google is still using v2 on desktop currently, (and through that embeds in business photos and art project),  and that with the final cease of v2 all these panoramic street views will be automatically displayed solely in html5, as flash street view player will be ceased too. That option would make sense.

Comment: @ManoMarks any hints? anyone? someone on the whole earth must know about it......